# Ez Publish create file input field inside feedback_form

Tags: forms, file-upload, ezpublish

There's anyone around here who knows how to create a contact-form (maybe extending the feedback_form class) with a file input field (using ez-publish v.4.3)?

any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The built-in "ezbinaryfile" datatype (labeled "File" when editing a content class) does not support information collection.

A Community contribution enhances the default "File" datatype with information collection support : 
http://projects.ez.no/index.php/enhanced_ezbinaryfile

Worth a try, although it does not claim to be compatible with eZ Publish 4.x / eZ Publish Community Project. An option, if not up-to-date, is to contribute to the project.

Comment: A new version is compatible with eZPublish 4.x : http://projects.ez.no/enhancedezbinaryfile